# MongoDB fetch rows before and after find result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB, (Mongoose on Node.js) I have a very large db of events, each event has a field `seq` (sequence), the order of the events.
I want to allow my users to find all the occurrences of a given event.

For example:
The user is searching for the event "ButtonClicked", I should return the all the locations that this event happened, in this example say [239, 1992, 5932]

This is easy, and I can just search for the requested event, and return the `seq` field.
Now I want to let the user view 20 events before, and 20 events after a specific `seq`.

It would have been great if I could do something like this:

`db.events.find( { id:"ButtonClicked", seq: 1992 } ).before(20).after(20);`

How can I do that?

Please note that the field `seq` might start with any number, and skip numbers, but it is incremental!
For example: [3,4,5,6,7,12,13,15,56,57...]

Also, note that the solution can ignore `seq`, I mentioned this field because I think that it can help the solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [comparison query operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query-comparison/), in particular `$gte` and `$lte`, using `seq` as a offset for the comparison.

Try:

```
var seqOffset = 1992;
db.events.find( { seq: { $gte: seqOffset - 20, $lte: seqOffset + 20 } } );
```

You could not get exactly 40 events, since as you mentioned `seq` might skip numbers.